# How to find if string contains letters and spaces (php)?

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

So I need to get value false or true if string contains not only letters of all european and east alphabets and  " "(space) and "-" minus. How to do such thing with some $a string?

Comment: What are “letters of all european and east alphabets” in your opinion?

Comment: I'm guessing latin and cyrrilic alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has to say on the subject of Unicode and PHP:

#### [Regular expressions on PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

> The most important set of regex functions start with `preg`. These functions are a PHP wrapper around the PCRE library (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions). **Anything said about the PCRE regex flavor in the regular expression tutorial on this website applies to PHP's `preg` functions**. You should use the `preg` functions for all new PHP code that uses regular expressions.
>
> A special option is the `/u` which turns on the Unicode matching mode, instead of the default 8-bit matching mode. You should specify `/u` for regular expressions that use `\x{FFFF}`, `\X` or `\p{L}` to match Unicode characters, graphemes, properties or **scripts**. PHP will interpret `'/regex/u'` as a UTF-8 string rather than as an ASCII string.

---

#### [Unicode support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

> The Unicode standard places each assigned code point (character) into one **script**. A script is a group of code points used by a particular human writing system. Some scripts like Thai correspond with a single human language. Other scripts like Latin span multiple languages.
>
> Very few regular expression engines support Unicode scripts today. Of all the flavors discussed in this tutorial, only the JGsoft engine, Perl and **PCRE can match Unicode scripts**. Here's a complete list of all Unicode scripts:
>
> - `\p{Cyrillic}`
> - [...rest omitted]

---

Therefore, if you want to see if a string consists **only** of letters in Cyrillic in PHP, you can try to match it against this regular expression:

```
/^\p{Cyrillic}*$/u
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\p{L&} -]+$/u', $a)) {
  # Only letters (any script), spaces and hyphens
} else {
  # Emtpy string or other characters too
}
```

`\p{L}` matches any character that can be part of a word in any script, including ideographs (e.g. Chinese characters).  `\p{L&}` matches only letters from alphabetic scripts (Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Thai, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are tackling a character set issue the wrong way, but I could be wrong...? A few gotchas that have tripped me up in the past..

- DOMDocument processes everything internally in UTF8, regardless.
- An include in a different character set
- Database not outputting in Unicode because of a lack of a "SET NAMES.." instruction.

Whats the code supposed to achieve? Maybe if we can look past your question to the next step, there's a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

**Pregmatch** is an easy way. You just need to add below condition.

> It will return true if **$name** contains letters and spaces only, else it will return false.

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", $name)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Hope it helps!